# issues with apple signin

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, apple-sign-in

Hi the problem im having is with a flutter app. A user can register manually inputting a email and password or with apple signin or google signin. If a user registered manually and then uses google or apple to signin without hiding the email and the email is the same email that was initially registered manually they will receive a error message saying this email is already registered. The problem is when a user hides their email with apple then a new user is created under this hidden email so the user unintentionally now has 2 accounts. How can I prevent this? thanks